# кластеризация объектов на яндекс картах

Tags: яндекс-карты

Как в апи яндекс карт можно кластиризовать метки для каждого дома в одну, так чтобы в кластеризованной метке показывалось количество помещенных в нее меток. метод ObjectManager кластеризует метки только при маленьком увеличении а при нажатии на метку, увеличивается масштаб и каждая метка в каждом доме отображается отдельно.

Answer (score -2):

Сделать кластеризацию с точностью до дома не получится, потому что у кластеризатора регулярная сетка. А запретить изменение масштаба по клику можно, для этого есть опция метки кластера: [clusterDisableClickZoom](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/ClusterPlacemark-docpage/#param-options.disableClickZoom).

Вот пример: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/clusterer_create